# Will Drill Leverage Hive indexing

Tags: hive, apache-drill, mapr

If we index a table in hive, Will drill leverage indexing while querying the hive table with hive plugin in drill.
It's cuz we have partitioned table in hive and the analytics query has a partitioned and non-partitioned column in where clause, so we want to index the non-partitioned column in hive.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Drill does not leverage Hive indices, but the Drill team is currently working on adding this feature for some storage layers. Please get in touch with us on the mailing list if you are still interested in having index support added for Hive http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/